# Move a certain row of data into column (reversal of existing macro)

Tags: vba, excel

Reference to solution provided here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231458

I need to do this in reverse, e.g.:

```
A E F G H I
B J K L M N
C O P Q R S
D T U V W X
```

to

```
A E
A F
A G
A H
A I
B J
B K
B L
B M
B N
C O
C P
C Q
C R
C S
D T
D U
D V
D W
D X
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sheet]

```
Sub foo()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
    row = 0

    For Each cell In rng
        col = 1
        Do Until cell.Offset(0, col) = ""
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Offset(row, 0) = cell
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Offset(row, 1) = cell.Offset(0, col)
            row = row + 1
            col = col + 1
        Loop
    Next cell


End Sub
```